# OSX sed: how to use the escape character in the second field of a `s` operation?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, terminal

On OSX:

```
bash-3.2$ echo "abc" | sed 's/b/\x1b[31mz\x1b[m/'
ax1b[31mzx1b[mc
```

Whereas on Linux:

```
$ echo "abc" | sed 's/b/\x1b[31mz\x1b[m/'
azc
```

and the z correctly shows up red.

Is this a limitation of bash 3.2? My Linux test here runs bash 4.1.2.

The weird thing is on my linux environment at work the bash is version below 3.2, and it *works there too*.

Also, this might be related but is probably not:

```
bash-3.2$ echo "abc" | sed 's/b/^[[31mz^[[m/'
31mz$'m/'azc
```

Again, specific to BSD sed. It's pretty puzzling: Seems like something is causing the shell or `sed` to echo some mangled portion of the command to the terminal somehow? It is always preceding the correct output of the command, however. Where's that dollar sign coming from?

(don't be confused by colors in my commands (which come after the cyan unicode character that looks like a less bent `>` which is my prompt), I use syntax highlighting with zsh)

[image]

Comment: Re the possibly related issue at the end: I have no idea what's going on there... can you pipe the result through `xxd` or something similar to find out exactly what's being produced?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OS X's version of sed doesn't do the escape substitutions you're asking for. You can get around this by using `$'...'` to have bash do the substitution before handing the string to sed:

```
$ echo "abc" | sed 's/b/\x1b[31mz\x1b[m/'
ax1b[31mzx1b[mc
$ echo "abc" | sed $'s/b/\x1b[31mz\x1b[m/'
azc
```

(You'll have to trust me the "z" is red in the second one.) But note that this may require that in some cases you may have to double-escape things you want sed to do the escape substitution on.

Comment: You got one better than me, I didn't know you could $ a sed expression and was working a less elegant example with a subshell so thanks for the lesson :-)

Comment: Awesome! This fixed both of the issues (check my edited OP). Do you happen to know how to explain what's going on with that second issue?

Comment: To clarify my last comment... This magical $'' syntax prevents the issue described in my OP's second section (the garbage that Linux systems tend to dump into the terminal prior to the result, it is not seen when this is used in a script)

Comment: @StevenLu Does your shell setup do anything like putting the current command in the terminal window's title bar? It looks to me like the shell is sending the command back to the terminal emulator in some form that the emulator is confused by...

Comment: Ooh. That's a good guess! I'll have to look into it later though.

Answer (score 2):

Oh. right so the shell version does not affect this. No idea why I thought that.

The culprit is just that BSD sed doesn't do translation, so the solution is just the <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> approach of using the raw escape byte in the sed command string.